# Bcrypt.hashSync returns false when checking updated password

Tags: javascript, mongoose, backend, mongoose-schema, bcrypt

I want the login to be successful but even though the password is updated in database and is being displayed as changed, the compareSync on bcrypt returns false.

```
    async login(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let email = req.body.email
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
    if (user) {
      if (user.schema.methods.isVerified) {
        let password: string = req.body.password
        let hashedPassword = user.password
        console.log(password, hashedPassword)
        console.log(user.schema.methods.checkPassword(password, hashedPassword))
        if (user.schema.methods.checkPassword(password, hashedPassword)) {
          res.json(dataResponse({ userId: user.id }, 200, 'Login sucess'))
        } else {
          res.json(dataResponse('', 200, 'Invalid email or password'))
        }
      } else {
        const tokenItem = await Token.findOne({ userId: user.id })
        if (tokenItem) {
          if (tokenItem.schema.methods.isNotExpired) {
            await Token.deleteMany().where({ userId: user._id })
            await tokenController.create({ userId: user._id, email: email })
            res.json(
            dataResponse(null, 406, 'Your\'e account is not verified,a new token has been sent to your email')
          )
          } else {
            await Token.deleteMany().where({ userId: user.id })
            await User.deleteMany().where({ _id: user.id })
            res.json(
              dataResponse(
                '',
                401,
                "Your account doesn't exist, please sign up "
              )
            )
          }
        } else{
            await tokenController.create({ userId: user._id, email: email })
            res.json(
                dataResponse(null, 406, 'Your\'e account is not verified,a new token has been sent to your email')
            )
        }
      }
    } else{
        res.json(dataResponse('', 401, 'This account doesn\'t exist, please sign up'))
    }
  }

  async forgotPassword(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let email = req.body.email 
    let password = req.body.password
    const user = await User.findOne({email:email})
    if(user){
      if(user.schema.methods.isVerified){
        await user.updateOne({ password })
        await user.save()
        res.json(dataResponse('', 200, 'Password reset successful'))
      } else {
        res.json(dataResponse('', 401, 'Your account is not verified please try logging in'))
      }
    } else {
      res.json(dataResponse('', 401, 'This account does not exist.'))
    }
  }
```

Above is the login functionality that I created to get the user logged in. I am using mongoose middleware to hash the password and check the hashed password

```
    userSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.password = bcrypt.hashSync(this.password, 10)
  next()
})
```

For hashing password

```
    userSchema.methods.checkPassword = function (
  password: string,
  hashedPassword: string
) {
return bcrypt.compareSync(password, hashedPassword)
}
```

For updating password. Now the problem is when I register and login, it works. However, when I update the password, then the bcrypt returns false.

```
    async forgotPassword(req: Request, res: Response) {
    let email = req.body.email 
    let password = req.body.password
    const user = await User.findOne({email:email})
    if(user){
      if(user.schema.methods.isVerified){
        await user.updateOne({ password })
        await user.save()
        res.json(dataResponse('', 200, 'Password reset successful'))
      } else {
        res.json(dataResponse('', 401, 'Your account is not verified please try logging in'))
      }
    } else {
      res.json(dataResponse('', 401, 'This account does not exist.'))
    }
  }
```

That is the method I used to update password.

Comment: Doesn't `updateOne` bypass `save`? What happens if you replace your `updateOne` call with `user.password = password` (and then still call `save`)?

Comment: It worked but can you tell me why that was the case, while debugging it showed that the password was changed and hashed.  @ruakh

Comment: Re: "debugging it showed that the password was changed and hashed": Oh, interesting! Well, one problem with your current design is that you hash the password without knowing if it's already been hashed. (Obviously bcrypt isn't idempotent.) So my guess would be that maybe your old code was triggering the hashing multiple times? To fix that, you should really use separate fields for hashed and unhashed passwords, and null out the unhashed password when you populate the hashed password. That way you can safely tell whether a password needs to be hashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the `updateOne`function was bypassing `mogoose.save` which resulted in the error. It worked when I used `user.password = password`.

Answer credit: [ruakh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/978917/ruakh)